# How to generate series for input containing character with number in python

Tags: python

Input contains mix of characters and numbers and last digits are numbers. I need to generate sequence user id containing characters and numbers

**Input :**

```
start of series : A10B00001 
number of entries : 100
```

**Output :**

```
A10B00001
A10B00002
A10B00003
A10B00004
.
.
A10B00100
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: are your series fixed or it can be any combination?

Comment: @PrakashDahal It can be combinations but last 3-5 digits are numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using regex and format string:

```
import re


def series(serie, n=100):
    _, str_, int_ = re.split(r'(.*[a-z|A-Z])', serie)
    return [f'{str_}{(int(int_)+i):05d}' for i in range(n)]


print(series('A10B00001', n=5))
>>> ['A10B00001', 'A10B00002', 'A10B00003', 'A10B00004', 'A10B00005']
```